# Devexpress GridControl : Prevent new row added automatically

Tags: insert, grid, devexpress, row

Please guide me how to prevent new rows added automatically on DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl

I want to control when new rows is added, in my case i'm using a keydown event (CTRL + I ) for this task. But the grid keep adding new rows automatically if i move the focus (cursor pointer) to the area right below to the last row and click.

[image]

The GridControl.MainView is a **BandedGridView**, which contains the datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the ValidateRow event. If you set `e.Valid = false` you wont add a new row. So check if your object is empty or invalid and just if the needed values are typed you give the row free.

```
private void grvMyView_ValidateRow(object sender, ValidateRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (grvMyView.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle))
            {
               MyObject obj = grvMyView.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as MyObject;

               e.Valid = obj.IsValid();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BandedGridView.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_NewItemRowPositiontopic) property. You can set its value to [`NewItemRowPosition.None`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridNewItemRowPositionEnumtopic) to hide new item row.
Another way is to handle [`BandedGridView.ShownEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event. Inside of this you can check if [`BandedGridView.FocusedRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic) property is equals to [`GridControl.NewItemRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument642) and cancel editor activation.
Here is example:

```
private void bandedGridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (bandedGridView1.FocusedRowHandle == GridControl.NewItemRowHandle)
    {
        // Do here additional checks if you need. After your checks set e.Cancel to true.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think this is gonna meet my need. The first solution will prevent row from appending since i only want to prevent to automatically appended rows. The second solution still show the appended row, the only difference is we can't edit it. Do you have in mind other solutions ? Thanks !

Comment: @hoangnnm Basically, the first solution are not preventing row from appending. It's only hides new item row, but you still can add new row in your code. What code are you using in yours keydown event (CTRL + I)? The second solution disable editing of new row. If editing is disabled the row cannot be added.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 15 you can simply set your TableView's NewItemRowPosition to NewItemRowPosition.None.  Be sure to call CommitEditing() on your TableView first.