# Xtragrid is creating next row automatically ,how to prevent it

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

Check if any column value is null for current row if null then do not create another row in xtragrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the documentation: [New Item Row Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument778)

> In the GridView, the new item row is an empty row that is used to
>   enter new records. It can be displayed above or below all data and
>   group rows. The new item row's position is specified by the GridView's
>   GridOptionsView.NewItemRowPosition property. If this property is set
>   to NewItemRowPosition.None, the new item row is hidden.

References:
[gridview adding new row without losing focus](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q269630)
[Devexpress GridControl : Prevent new row added automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481980/devexpress-gridcontrol-prevent-new-row-added-automatically)